# Extracting grades from a file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was recently given a homework assignment in python where I had to make a dictionary of fake student IDs and put their corresponding grades for various homeworks in a nested dictionary. The dictionary with their IDs I was able to make with no problems but I cannot seem to put their corresponding grades in.
An example of the contents of the files are:

```
807-49-0073
658-30-1272
544-78-7923
709-40-8165
492-42-7987
503-27-1729
840-12-4303
169-09-7157
560-33-3099
278-16-5335
097-26-3512
267-10-7633
979-49-6579
821-67-0672
393-36-5485
```

and then the one for their IDs AND grades:

```
267-10-7633 66
709-40-8165 71
097-26-3512 78
807-49-0073 83
169-09-7157 73
278-16-5335 79
979-49-6579 79
544-78-7923 85
560-33-3099 73
840-12-4303 62
821-67-0672 87
503-27-1729 8
267-10-7633 85
979-49-6579 60
503-27-1729 62
821-67-0672 62
393-36-5485 15
560-33-3099 38
097-26-3512 80
658-30-1272 85
278-16-5335 84
169-09-7157 70
840-12-4303 73
544-78-7923 60
560-33-3099 87
840-12-4303 75
979-49-6579 96
492-42-7987 85
544-78-7923 72
169-09-7157 82
278-16-5335 67
709-40-8165 96
393-36-5485 87
097-26-3512 85
821-67-0672 86
278-16-5335 97
393-36-5485 73
503-27-1729 78
979-49-6579 24
821-67-0672 87
544-78-7923 73
709-40-8165 34
097-26-3512 73
840-12-4303 100
807-49-0073 75
267-10-7633 74
658-30-1272 94
492-42-7987 87
```

So I need to take the last 2-digit number and put it with the corresponding student. Some are repeated. This is my code so far, but I am currently stuck.

```
def create_dictionary(idfilename, hwfilename):
    hwL = []
    dict1 = {}
    dict2 = {'hw': hwL}

    ids = open(idfilename, 'r').read().splitlines()
    hws = open(hwfilename, 'r').read().splitlines()

    for i in ids:
        dict1[i] = dict1.get(i, dict2)

    for k in hws:
        hwL = k.split(' ')
```

Comment: What do you think `for k in hws: hwL = k.split(' ')` is doing?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to separate the ID from the grade, and then match them up from the nested list.

Answer (score -1):

I can't debug right now but this should be close:

```
import csv
#assuming the files are .csvs
def create_dictionary(idfilename, hwfilename):
    #declare the field names of the dictionaries so we can refer to them later
    field_names1 = ['id']
    field_names2 = ['id','grade']
    dictOf_Ids = csv.DictReader(open(idfilename,fieldnames=field_names1))
    dictOf_hw = csv.DictReader(open(hwfilename,fieldnames=field_names2))
    #will look something like this: [{'id':'560-33-3099','grades':[76,56,42]}]
    listOf_dictionaries =[{}]   

    #read through the records in the id dictionary line by line
    for id in dictOf_Ids:
        #each id will have its own list of grades
        grades = []
        #read through the records in the hw dictionary line by line
        for hw in dictOf_hw:
            #if the ids match, get the grade from the hw dict and add it to our list of grades for that id
            if id.get('id') == hw.get('id'):
                grade = hw.get('grade')
                grades.append(grade)
            else:
                #do nothing because the id's don't match
                pass
        #add the dictionary to the list
        dict = {'id':id,'grades':grades}
        listOf_dictionaries.append(dict)
```

Comment: We haven't really done much with importing modules so I don't think my professor would accept this. Can this be done without importing csv?

Comment: Yes. The csv.DictReader basically just parses the .csv files and dumps them into Dictionaries. Just assume dictOf_Ids and dictOf_hw are the dictionaries you posted above